# Access and edit Image inside Button on Button click in code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have a Listview built like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="listprimi" RelativePanel.Below="primi" ItemsSource="{x:Bind obs_prims2}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Button Tag="{Binding id}" Grid.Column="0" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100" Background="White" Click="selectMeal0">
                      <Image Name="sel0" Width="80" Height="80" Source="Images/ic_uncheck.png" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" />
                  </Button>
                  <Image Width="120" Height="120" Margin="30,0,0,0" Source="{Binding idImg}" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" />
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding descr}" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" Height="100" Name="namemeal" Padding="60,15" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="26.7"/>
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

I would like to change the image named "sel0" which is inside the button when the button is clicked. I have set the code behind function selectMeal0 but I have no idea on how to do it.
In addition I would also like to change the images of all the other elements of the list in the same function.
I have tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375375/how-do-i-access-a-control-inside-a-xaml-datatemplate) but it doesn't work.

UPDATE:
This is the class

```
public class Pasto : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string descr { get; set; }
    public ImageSource idImg { get; set; }
    private ImageSource imgChecked;
    public ImageSource ImgChecked {
        get { return imgChecked; }
        set
        {
            if (imgChecked != value)
            {
                imgChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ImgChecked");
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

I've changed the ListView like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="listprimi" RelativePanel.Below="primi" ItemsSource="{x:Bind obs_prims2}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Button Tag="{Binding id}" Grid.Column="0" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100" Background="White" Click="selectMeal0">
                      <Image Name="sel0" Width="80" Height="80" Source="{Binding ImgChecked}" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" />
                  </Button>
                  <Image Width="120" Height="120" Margin="30,0,0,0" Source="{Binding idImg}" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" />
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding descr}" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" Height="100" Name="namemeal" Padding="60,15" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="26.7"/>
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

so that the image I'd like to edit is ImageChecked in the class.
The function selectMeal should change all the images to "unchecked" and then the selected item's image to "checked".

Comment: What you want is similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319063/wpf-change-button-background-image-when-clicked . You should use a DataTrigger bound to a bool property

Comment: thank you @MartinoBordin but VisualStudio says to me that  `<Style.Triggers>` is not a recognize member for Universal Windows Apps!

Comment: You could use a _DataTriggerBehavior_ or _VisualStateManager_ as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929071/trigger-element-xaml-is-not-supported-in-a-windows-universal-app-project

Answer (score 0):

in `selectMeal0`, you get access to the sender object, which is a `Button` in this case. The Button have `Content` property, which in turn containts the `Image`. At this point you can do anything to the Image.

**BUT**

you can also bind the source of the image to a property of your model. And make change to the model to update the image.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change `Image` inside your `DataTemplate` of your `ListView`, you should change the necessary item from your collection on button click:

So, you have a collection `obs_prims2` as `ItemsSource` for `ListView`. Then you need to take the the one item from your collection `obs_prims2`. For example:

```
var item=obs_prims2.FirstOrDefault();
```

then set new Image address:

```
item.idImg="C:/1.png";
```

Moreover, your Model class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to show any changes. For example:

```
public class Book : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string title;
    public string Title {
       get { return title; }
       set {
           title = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("Title");
       }         
    }    

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(String info) 
    {
       if (PropertyChanged != null) {
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

**Update:**

To get an item that you want, then you can get item by index, like that
`Person person = Persons[1];`. For example:

```
private void FillDataGridByTypeCollection()
{
    Persons.Add(new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Ben" });
    Persons.Add(new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Joseph" });
    Persons.Add(new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Jon" });
    Persons.Add(new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Magnus Montin" });
    Persons.Add(new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Andy" });
    Person person = Persons[1];
}

private ObservableCollection<Person> persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
{
   get { return persons; }
   set { persons = value; }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Since the Image in the item source is not the one I'd like to change, I think this is not what I'm looking for. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @Janinho67 it is the way that you can change not only `Image`, but any item in your model. It is just an example how to edit items. It is the common way to change your model.

Comment: I'm trying to use your suggestion. Starting to see some result. I'd like to ask you something. If I want to select one particular element which is not the first, how can I do it?