# Can you turn a button into an image when its clicked in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

Trying to either change the background image of a button when it's clicked or change the button into an image when clicked.

```
 var brush = new ImageBrush
            {
                ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("image1.jpg", UriKind.Relative))
            };
            Button1.Background = brush;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically changing button icon in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971300/programmatically-changing-button-icon-in-wpf)

Comment: WPF/UWP and XAML are deigned with the MVVM pattern in mind. While you can use other approaches, doing so misses about 90% of it's power and runs into problem at every other corner. I wrote a introduction into MVVM a few yeras back: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf | This Image like rerepsents one of two things. 1) A Bool being set 2) A bunch of settings you itterate through. In thise case it is a mater of basic binding, plus maybe a converter.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using UWP or WPF, you can do it in this way (which is exactly what you already have):

```
ImageBrush brush1 = new ImageBrush();
brush1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("uri to image"));
btn.Background = brush1;
```

or as described here: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971300/programmatically-changing-button-icon-in-wpf/5973592#5973592)

Comment: No im using wpf

Comment: @AnirudhShankar what about set the image in the same position of the button, change the image visible property value to false, and when the button is clicked, the button has the visible value to false and the image its value visible to true.

Comment: For  WPF you can use exactly the same code as for UWP. Both have XAML and code behind. Otherwise the code you are showing here is exactly what OP already has. The WinForms part is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you @clemens, you are right, I've edited my answer